# Sequentially compact $\Rightarrow \inf_{x\in A}\varepsilon_{x}=:2\varepsilon_{0}>0$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I've highlighted the sentence which I dont quite understand. Maybe I should say, that I interpret $\inf_{x\in A}\varepsilon_{x}$ as the greatest lower bound of $E_{x}$ - if this is wrong, then I need some more comments on this in particular. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is merely using the following fact :

> If $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded below, and $\alpha = \inf S$, then for any $\delta > 0$, there exists $y \in S$ such that
>   $$
> \alpha \leq y < \alpha+\delta
> $$

Consider the set
$$
S = \{\epsilon_x : x\in A\}
$$
and $\alpha = \inf_{x\in a}\epsilon_x$. What the argument says is the following :

If $\alpha = 0$, then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $1/n$ is not a lower bound for $S$. Hence, there exists some $x_n\in A$ such that
$$
\epsilon_{x_n} < 1/n
$$
This is the sequence $\{x_n\}$ that is being chosen there.

Comment: Ok. But is it correct, that these $\varepsilon_{x}$ is also extracted from the set $E_x$, or has it nothing to do with that ?

Comment: It is extracted from $E_x$, but this part of the argument has nothing to do with $E_x$ per se.